# Why Postgres does not perform index scan on the first column of concatenated index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a table `employees` with 10k records.

```
postgres=# select count(*) from employees;
 count
-------
 10000
(1 row)
```

I created a concatenated index with `subsidiary_id` as the first column.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_indexes where schemaname = 'public';
 schemaname | tablename |  indexname   | tablespace |                                           indexdef

------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----
 public     | employees | employees_pk |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX employees_pk ON public.employees USING btree (subsidiary_id, employee_
id)
(1 row)
```

My expectation:
If I search by "subsidiary_id", it should use index scan, and if I search by "employee_id", it should use seq scan (full table scan).

```
postgres=# explain (format json) SELECT first_name, last_name, subsidiary_id, phone_number
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name  = 'WINAND'
   AND subsidiary_id = 30
;
                        QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------
 [                                                        +
   {                                                      +
     "Plan": {                                            +
       "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",                   +
       "Parallel Aware": false,                           +
       "Async Capable": false,                            +
       "Relation Name": "employees",                      +
       "Alias": "employees",                              +
       "Startup Cost": 23.79,                             +
       "Total Cost": 1492.60,                             +
       "Plan Rows": 1,                                    +
       "Plan Width": 19,                                  +
       "Recheck Cond": "(subsidiary_id = '30'::numeric)", +
       "Filter": "((last_name)::text = 'WINAND'::text)",  +
       "Plans": [                                         +
         {                                                +
           "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",              +
           "Parent Relationship": "Outer",                +
           "Parallel Aware": false,                       +
           "Async Capable": false,                        +
           "Index Name": "employees_pk",                  +
           "Startup Cost": 0.00,                          +
           "Total Cost": 23.79,                           +
           "Plan Rows": 1000,                             +
           "Plan Width": 0,                               +
           "Index Cond": "(subsidiary_id = '30'::numeric)"+
         }                                                +
       ]                                                  +
     }                                                    +
   }                                                      +
 ]
(1 row)

postgres=# explain (format json) SELECT first_name, last_name, subsidiary_id, phone_number
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name  = 'WINAND'
   AND employee_id = 2
;
                       QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------
 [                                                     +
   {                                                   +
     "Plan": {                                         +
       "Node Type": "Index Scan",                      +
       "Parallel Aware": false,                        +
       "Async Capable": false,                         +
       "Scan Direction": "Forward",                    +
       "Index Name": "employees_pk",                   +
       "Relation Name": "employees",                   +
       "Alias": "employees",                           +
       "Startup Cost": 0.29,                           +
       "Total Cost": 235.14,                           +
       "Plan Rows": 1,                                 +
       "Plan Width": 19,                               +
       "Index Cond": "(employee_id = '2'::numeric)",   +
       "Filter": "((last_name)::text = 'WINAND'::text)"+
     }                                                 +
   }                                                   +
 ]
(1 row)
```

To my surprise, Postgres uses "index Scan" on the second query (search by employee id).

Why?

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT first_name, last_name, subsidiary_id, phone_number
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name  = 'WINAND'
   AND employee_id = 166
;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using employees_pk on employees  (cost=0.29..231.30 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=7.348..7.349 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (employee_id = '166'::numeric)
   Filter: ((last_name)::text = 'WINAND'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=39
 Planning Time: 0.476 ms
 Execution Time: 7.431 ms
(7 rows)
```

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT first_name, last_name, subsidiary_id, phone_number
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name  = 'WINAND'
   AND subsidiary_id = 30
;
                                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on employees  (cost=23.79..1492.60 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=11.668..11.668 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (subsidiary_id = '30'::numeric)
   Filter: ((last_name)::text = 'WINAND'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 999
   Heap Blocks: exact=144
   Buffers: shared hit=150
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on employees_pk  (cost=0.00..23.79 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=2.198..2.198 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (subsidiary_id = '30'::numeric)
         Buffers: shared hit=6
 Planning Time: 1.001 ms
 Execution Time: 11.838 ms
(11 rows)

postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT first_name, last_name, subsidiary_id, phone_number
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name  = 'WINAND'
   AND subsidiary_id = 2
;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on employees  (cost=23.61..1480.56 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=19.284..19.286 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (subsidiary_id = '2'::numeric)
   Filter: ((last_name)::text = 'WINAND'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 977
   Heap Blocks: exact=670
   Buffers: shared hit=676
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on employees_pk  (cost=0.00..23.61 rows=977 width=0) (actual time=1.170..1.170 rows=977 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (subsidiary_id = '2'::numeric)
         Buffers: shared hit=6
 Planning Time: 0.371 ms
 Execution Time: 19.351 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: How selective is the predicate `subsidiary_id = 30`? In short, what percentage of rows of the table will this predicate select?

Comment: The storage of an index is generally smaller that the storage of the all table... To perform quicker, the sql engine can do a seek or a scan into the index pages.

Comment: The JSON format is not really intended to be read by humans. `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` is a better way to show a plan to other humans.

Comment: Your question seems to be opposite of your title.

Comment: @TheImpaler it will return 10% rows (1k / 10k total). When I change it to subsidiary_id = 2 (return 2 / 10k), the execution plan uses index scan. 
It still doesn't explain why ` WHERE last_name  = 'WINAND'
   AND employee_id = 2` uses index-scan.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output. Perhaps some configuration parameters are set in interesting ways.

Answer (score 1):

When an index is scanned for a condition that does *not* include the first index column, PostgreSQL has to read the complete index. Since the search returns quite a few false positives (not all conditions are indexed), PostgreSQL prefers a bitmap index scan, so that it doesn't have to visit table pages more than once.

Now this is certainly more costly than using an index that matches the query better, but if the table is much larger than the index, it can still be cheaper than a sequential scan of the whole table. True, I don't see PostgreSQL taking that path often, but the optimizer is impartial: it will consider all remotely reasonable plans and choose the one it thinks is cheapest.

That leaves the possibility that PostgreSQL got it wrong. However, all the estimates are good, so I'd expect this plan to be good too. You can test if that is true by setting `enable_indexscan` and `enable_bitmapscan` to `off` (with `SET` in your current session). Then test how a sequential scan would perform.

If you lower `random_page_cost`, you *might* get an index scan that *might* perform even better.

Comment: When I turned off bitmapscan, it uses seqscan...???
```
                                                  QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on employees  (cost=0.00..1697.00 rows=1000 width=19) (actual time=0.098..18.622 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Filter: (subsidiary_id = '30'::numeric)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 9000
   Buffers: shared hit=1572
 Settings: enable_bitmapscan = 'off'
 Planning Time: 0.479 ms
 Execution Time: 18.776 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: You see the costs are no that much different, as are the execution times, but the sequential scan is slightly slower.

Comment: I expect it would use `index scan`. Why would seqscan has lower cost?

Comment: Because it actually is faster. A bitmap index scan is best if the index scan returns many rows (in your case, 1000).